# Why does the shell run the incorrect Python?

Tags: terminal, python, path, zsh

I am coming from an Ubuntu environment, and since you can set Python 3 to be the first-class Python in Ubuntu (as in, you call `python` and you get Python 3), I wanted to do the same on the Mac I've started using.

After trying to point the `/usr/bin/python` symbolic link to `/usr/bin/python3` and finding it failed, I did some research and found that [Apple puts some protection on `/usr/bin` which has to be updated by changing a flag in Recovery mode, and is not generally recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38435256/809289).  So I thought I would create a new `/usr/bin/local/python` link to `/usr/bin/python3` and that would work since `/usr/bin/local/python` comes before `/usr/bin/python` in the path.

Here's what I've tried.  The results have me confused.

```
username@Machine ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.18
username@Machine ~ % sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python
username@Machine ~ % sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
username@Machine ~ % which python
/usr/local/bin/python
username@Machine ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.18
username@Machine ~ % echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
username@Machine ~ % /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.9
username@Machine ~ % ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  16 Dec  9 12:37 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3
username@Machine ~ % hash -r
username@Machine ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.18
username@Machine ~ % whence python   
/usr/local/bin/python
```

I should add that I'm running zsh, and I'm used to running bash.  Why don't I get version 3.8.9 when I run `python --version` or `/usr/local/bin/python --version`?

Comment: What does `type python` return after running `hash -r`?

Comment: As you probably know, this is easy to fix on a Linux box with `update-alternatives`. I use MacPorts instead of Homebrew, but unfortunately there is no MacPort for `update-alternatives` - perhaps there is for Homebrew??

Comment: Given that Python 2 and Python 3 have so many incompatibilities, I find your approach a bit questionable. You could for instance put a directory in front of your `PATH`, and in that direcory you create a symbolic link `python`, pointing to your python3 installation. Another possibility (if you plan to use this feature only interactively) would be to create a function or an alias.

Comment: I've decided to let this go and just use pyenv instead.

Comment: @Seamus but for macports you don't need this - use port select to choose which python to use

Comment: Some parts of macOS rely on python2 e.g. xattr on several versions so don't try to alter /usr/bin/python

Comment: @mmmmmm: I'm not sure `port select` and `update-alternatives` cover the same bases. `update-alternatives` operates out of `/etc/alternatives`, I'm not sure what `port select` uses. But I do agree it's better than nothing :)

Comment: But the correct answer or python is use venv

Comment: @nohillside, There was no output just as in the question.

Comment: Is there a python in /opt/homebrew/bin?

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't re-hash the shell you are currently in.  Either use:

```
% hash -r
```

Or restart the shell.

`/usr/bin/which` does not tell you what the shell is going to do, because it is not a shell builtin... it searches `$PATH`.

If you want to know what the shell is actually going to do, use `whence`, which *is* a shell builtin.

Having said this, since you have decided to use Homebrew, why aren't you using Homebrew's python?  Python 3.8.9 is the one from the Apple CLT.

Comment: I did try exiting the terminal and restarting before making this post.  I ran the other commands you suggested, but I seem to be having the same problem.  I've added the output to the question.

Comment: I've decided to let this go and just use pyenv instead.

Comment: _because it is not a shell builtin_ : This is not entirely true. The OP unfortunately tagged the question by _bash_ **and** _zsh_, which of course is a bad idea in the first place; but in zsh, `which` **is** a builtin. In bash it is not.

Comment: It isn't in `ksh` either.

Comment: @MarcWilson which is a builtin command in zsh see the manual https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-which

Comment: @mmmmmm It's an alias for `whence -c`.